# android:fitsSystemWindows="true" not working for my view

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am using single activity over which I have used all fragments. I am developing a screen of gallery fragment in which I am showing slide show with bottom recycler view to slide pages of slide show. The bottom view of gallery recycler is getting hide from bottom navigation bar.
What I have used:- I have added window flag to gallery fragment from main activity backstackChangeListner

```
  activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
  activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
```

Here is my gallery fragment view

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="viewImageVM"
        type="com.geenie.consumer.viewmodel.ViewImageViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <!--
            this is my slide show view pager for gallery
    -->
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>


    <!--
            this is for backward slide in my slide show
    -->
    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#BF3e434c"
        android:elevation="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:onClick='@{(v)->viewImageVM.switchToComponent("Backward")}'
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back_arrow_gray"
        android:tint="@color/gray"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottomRecycler"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bottomRecycler" />


    <!--
    this is bottom icons of image for selecting the image
     -->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/bottomRecycler"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <!--
    this is for forward slide in my slide show
    -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/end"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#BF3e434c"
        android:elevation="@dimen/margin_large"

        android:onClick='@{(v)->viewImageVM.switchToComponent("Forward")}'
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back_arrow_gray"
        android:tint="@color/gray"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottomRecycler"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bottomRecycler" />
    <!--
            this is my custom toolbar
    -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:onClick='@{(v)->viewImageVM.switchToComponent("Back")}'
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:tint="@color/gray"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back_arrow_gray" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:tint="@color/gray"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:src="@drawable/trash_white"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_normal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontFamily="@font/sfprodisplay_bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have used `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` attribute in recyclerview which is getting hidden by navigation bar still no effect is getting seen in that my current screen. Please see screenshot of what I have achieved till now. Please help me I have used       android:fitsSystemWindows="true" earlier also which worked fine. Now I am missing somewhere.Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks
[image]